# Why doesn't this struct serialize?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have the following struct:

```
public struct Declarations
{
 public const string SchemaVersion = "urn:ean.ucc:gdsn:2";
}
```

And the SchemaVersion is used by some XmlElements which are trying to be serialized like this:

```
[XmlElement(Type=typeof(SomeGarbage),ElementName="moreJunk",IsNullable=false,Form=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified,Namespace=Declarations.SchemaVersion)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public SomeType __someMember;
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to run sgen.exe on my dll:

Error 1 There was an error reflecting type 'BigHammer.CINParser.Messages.Declarations'
Error 2 The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\sgen.exe" /force "C:\Users\mstoddard\teamserver_source\GDSN\CINParser\CINParser\bin\Debug\BigHammer.CINParser.dll"
" exited with code 1.

I tried making the struct a class, no help
I tried adding a default constructor, no help

Thoughts?

===Update===
It looks like Visual Studio was hiding some information, I have The same classes defined in two different CLR namespaces but not XML namespaces:

Error: There was an error reflecting type 'BigHammer.CINParser.Messages.Declarations'.
  - Types 'BigHammer.CINParser.Messages.Declarations' and 'BigHammer.CINParser.Messages.urn_ean_ucc_2.Declarations' both use the XML type name, 'Declarations',from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xml serializer serializes only properties.

Wrap your variables.

```
class Cro
{
     public Cro
     {
          _atia="my const value";
     }
     private string _atia; // won't be serialized
     public string Atia //  will be serialized
     {
          get
          {
               return _atia;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hm, on second thoughts, do you use XMLSerializer at all?

Comment: I don't use XmlSerializer, I use sgen.exe.  I think it does the same thing, but at compile time.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Can you try wrapping your members?  When I use XML serializer, I always have private fields and public members that get serialized.

Comment: Problem is that the only member in that struct is a const.  Even if I change it to a static, I get "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression..."

Comment: The member being accessed needs to be const to ensure that it doesn't change at runtime.  That would screw up serialization.

Comment: No it doesn't.  Initialize backing field in constructor, then provide ONLY get accessor.  Or, if that's the problem for the serializer, provide SET accessor that doesn't touch your backing field.

Answer (score 2):

Serialisation only applies to instance data.

Static/Const are data tied to the class.

Eg In the given app domain Declarations.SchemaVersion can only be a single value. So there is no instance data to serialise.